# C printf with %f whose decimal places is based on %d?

Tags: c, printf

I can print to four decimal places with `printf("Value: %0.4f\n", value)`; however, is there a way to make the number of decimals a value inserted with `%d`?, for example, something like:

```
double x = 3.434244;
int decimalPlaces  = 4;
printf("Value: %0.%df\n", x, decimalPlaces);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `*` in place of the field width or the precision, in which case an `int` is expected to fill in the value.

```
printf("Value: %0.*f\n", decimalPlaces, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

@dbush's answer is the way yo go. But for completeness, you can also format the formatting string:

```
sprintf(fmt, "Value: %%.%df\n", decimalPlaces);
printf(fmt, x);
```

Note the double `%%` to escape `%` in `printf()`.